# Is python & tableau enough to become data analyst?

Tags: data-mining, visualization, data-science-model

Currently, I working as SEO Analyst. I want to become a data analyst and so I have started learning python with data science from udemy course.
Can Anyone help me with guidance to learn data analytics?

Comment: Since this is "opinion based", the question is not suitable for this forum. However, knowing Python, Tableau ist quite a good start. There are so many different jobs out there; just need to find the right start. Looking into R (which is easy to learn if you know Python) could be a further benefit, also some SQL can be helpful. But this - of course - is just my opinion.